# IPhone SDK - Receive events from a nested view

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm implementing a card game.
In this game I have a Board that is an UIView and he holds Cards that are also UIView objects that contains images etc...
My question is what is the best way to receive events in the UIViewController from the inner Card views?
Should I use the NSNotificationCenter and register to a general "cardSelected" event?
or should I use delegates somehow and have the UIViewController listen to a delegate from the board (and the board listen to to a delegate from the cards etc...)

Thanks,
Netanel

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, you know how to both make it work using notifications and using the way of hooking up the event to the board and through the board with delegation to the viewcontroller.. So that's more a software engineering question than an iOS development one? Anyway, i'd use the board to receive the UIControl events, and from there send a pretty delegate method to whatever object manages the game logic above the board

Comment: Yes, its a design question not an "HOW TO DO IT" one. thank for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say using the NSNotificationCenter is cleaner solution simply for the fact you don't have to keep passing the delegate through all the classes. Thats just personal preference, either approach would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter is very convenient when there are an arbitrary number of receivers. You could use it even if there is only one receiver (like in this case), but technically, it seems to be less efficient than sending a message directly to the receiver (as in the delegation). Probably the performance wouldn't matter in your case, but personally notifications seem too expensive in this case for me. If what you want is to notify the controller of the board view about the card view's events, then register the board view controller as a delegate of card views, and send a message to the delegate when a card is selected.

Perhaps a better way would be, if each of your game logic, the board view and the card view is complicated and may be separately reused in other applications, to have a separate game logic class object, and let the card views and the board view have this logic class object as a delegate.